# c# how to avoid installing with administrative rights

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have a windows app developed in VS2010 and a setup project within the solution. I was using the registry for storing certain application settings (legacy functionality) but I removed that now and everything will be stored within the settings file. However I want to prevent having any issues during installation. I would like the installer to install without any administrative rights if possible. What are the things I need to look at in order to have an installer like that? This is an app targeting environments with a lot of security and required IT support so I would like to minimise their involvement as much as possible. If a simple desktop user can install the app without any rights that would be great.

Comment: Are you set on using the standard installer that comes with VS2010? If not I would reccomend [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), it is sweeet...

Comment: Actually I am not stuck with VS2010 but I wouldn't want to invest huge amounts of time. I am having a look at NSIS at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to make sure your installer does not install anything anywhere where you need to have elevated priveleges. It must be a per-user install, no common shortcuts, nothing in program files, etc. That should be sufficient although I never use Visual Studios default setup and deployment projects. I would recommend looking at WiX http://wixtoolset.org/, it is what I use daily and what Visual Studio itself was installed with, however of the main installation software/tools should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I dont install in C:\Program Files where then?

Comment: Somewhere in the user's profile, such as there Documents directory. You could also let the user set the install location, but if they tried installing to a place like Program Files the installer would need to elevate or it would fail. Also, you may want to think about scenarios where directories in the user's profile (such as Documents) are located on the network and not the local machine. That could cause some interesting scenarios.